# Access database by many users simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If a database is access by many users then it is necessary to take lock on database? If YES then how to take lock on table or database? What is problem if not taking a lock?
    For Example: If a user update table and some one fetch data from this table then it is necessary to take lock on this table?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Transactions`:

When the user updates the table, the `UPDATE` statement should be inside `START TRANSACTION` clause.  If the UPDATE succeeds, then `COMMIT` else `ROLLBACK`.

You can lock tables with `LOCK TABLES`. However, if you lock tables with LOCK TABLES, all updates stall until integrity checks are made. If you obtain a `READ LOCAL` lock (as opposed to a write lock) for a table that enables concurrent inserts at the end of the table, reads are permitted, as are inserts by other clients.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Comment: What is problem if not taking a lock?

Comment: It's not a simple question, or answer. You need to do a little research on database transactions.

Comment: @HimanshuMohta You should take a look at Isolation levels. An introduction can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Dirty_reads_.28Uncommitted_Dependency.29

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your transaction isolation level MySQL will automatically issue locks. How they interact is determined by the transaction isolation level.

Only in very specific situations will you manually request locks on a table or database resource. Most of the time this is done by MySQL for you. The above answers has links which will be very important to read and understand.